# SED print one line within a block where block-close is either next block or EOF

Tags: sed

I am trying to extract the `path` for the appropriate `[module]` from a standard rsyncd.conf file, and I would like to be able to keep the .conf file completely standard without any special consideration for line spacing, ordering, comments, etc.

My rsyncd.conf file looks something like this:

```
pid file = /usr/home/rsync/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /usr/home/rsync/rsyncd.lock
log file = /usr/home/rsync/rsyncd.log
uid = rsync
gid = wheel
fake super = yes
use chroot = no
munge symlinks = no
max connections = 64

[backup2]
path = /vol2/backup
comment = backups on vol2
read only = no
hosts allow=redacted   
[backup3]
path = /vol3/backup
comment = backups on vol3
read only = no
hosts allow=redacted
```

If I do something like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    MODULE=$1
    sed -n '/\['$MODULE'\]/,/^\[/path.*=/p;}; ' rsyncd.conf
```

It will work fine for the "backup2" module, but will not extract the path for the "backup3" module.  If I alter the sed command like this:

```
    sed -n '/\['$MODULE'\]/,${/path.*=/p;}; ' rsyncd.conf
```

I can get the path for module3, but then a search for module 2 returns the path for both modules, since the end range is EOF.

I have tried adding a quit `q;` command after the print `p;` but then I don't get anything.

How can I make this work without making changes or requiring particular formatting in the rsyncd.conf file?

Comment: So from that file you are looking for an output like `/vol2/backup` and `/vol3/backup`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk like this:

```
module="$1"
awk -F'[= ]+' -v m="$module" '$0 ~ m { p=1 } p && /path/ { print $2; p=0 }' conf
```

The `-F` sets the field separator to a regular expression group containing one or more `=` or . This means that the first field `$1` is the part before the equals sign (e.g. `path`) and the second field `$2` is the part after (e.g. `/vol2/backup`). The variable `m` is set to the name of the module.

The scripts sets a flag `p` when the module name is encountered. When the flag is set and `/path/` is matched, the value of the second field is printed and the flag is unset.

Testing it out:

```
$ module="backup2"
$ awk -F'[= ]+' -v m="$module" '$0 ~ m { p=1 } p && /path/ { print $2; p=0 }' conf
/vol2/backup
$ module="backup3"
$ awk -F'[= ]+' -v m="$module" '$0 ~ m { p=1 } p && /path/ { print $2; p=0 }' conf
/vol3/backup
```

Comment: Does `-F'[= ]+'` set the field separator to `=<space>` or something else? What does the `+` do there?

Comment: I've just added to my explanation, hopefully that makes everything clear.

Comment: I had no idea that `awk -F` could take in regex! That's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `sed` this should do the trick:

```
sed -rn 's|path = (.*)|\1|p' rsyncd.conf
```

Output:

```
/vol2/backup
/vol3/backup
```

Comment: As I understand it, the idea is that in selecting "backup2" or "backup3", the output is limited to only the path within that section.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Do you mean OP wants to search on `backup` instead of `path`?

Comment: I mean that if `$MODULE` is "backup2", then only the path corresponding to the [backup2] section is displayed.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. I assumed (probably incorrectly) that OP was going to loop through all `[MODULES]` and so I thought my answer would save some time.